# Display input field's value on keypress in another input field divided by php variable

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I am trying to display #output value into another input field so far I found 
this ->  http://jsbin.com/oleto5/5/edit?html,js,output
here you can see when type into input field showing entered data into < div> which id=output `<input id="txt" type="text" />`

> what I am looking to achieve: 
> 1 - Changes in html- I am looking to show #output as a value into another input field like this `<input id="output" type="text" />`
>   
> 2 - Changes in script - I also want to do changes in calculation i have php variable named $final_rate for, i want to "Output" deivide by php variable $final_rate

**Expected Code Example**

```
<body>
  <input id="txt" type="text" />
  <input id="output" type="text" value=""/>
</body>
<?php $final_rate = "121";?>
   <script>
 $(function(){
      $('#txt').keydown(function(){
        setTimeout(function() {
          $('#output').text($('#txt').val());
        }, 50);
      });
    });
</script>
```

in above example if we enter 10000 in #txt input field we should get an out of 82.644 in simple words "10000/121 = 82.644"

Comment: Javascript does not have access to php variables.  PHP runs on the server.  Javascript runs on the client's browser.  If you want javascript to have access to the value of `121` you are going to have to write it to the page in a manner that the client can get access to it.

Comment: Also what's up with the setTimeout in the keydown event?

Comment: `setTimeout` in the `keydown` is really odd

Comment: @Taplar that's a challenge we need to find a solution to use php variable data for javascript use, i think we can echo it somewhere or somehow; it's hard to archive but it's possible

Answer (score 1):

```
<body>
  <input id="txt" type="text" />
  <input id="output" type="text" value=""/>

  <script>
    //put the value in a javascript variable as a Number
    var finalRate = <?php echo "121"; ?>;

    $(function(){
      //bind on the input event, which happens any time the value of the input changes
      $('#txt').on('input', function(e){
        //console log the rate just for debugging
        console.log(finalRate);
        //console log the math just for debugging
        console.log(parseFloat(e.target.value)/finalRate);
        //turn the value in the input into a Number, and perform the math
        $('#output').val(parseFloat(e.target.value)/finalRate);
      });
    });
  </script>
</body>
```

```js
//put the value in a javascript variable as a Number
var finalRate = 121;//'<?php echo "121"; ?>;

$(function() {
  //bind on the input event, which happens any time the value of the input changes
  $('#txt').on('input', function(e) {
    //console log the rate just for debugging
    console.log(finalRate);
    //console log the math just for debugging
    console.log(parseFloat(e.target.value) / finalRate);
    //turn the value in the input into a Number, and perform the math
    $('#output').val(parseFloat(e.target.value) / finalRate);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="txt" type="text" />
<input id="output" type="text" value="" />
```

Comment: your math function is working, but need to improve it, #output data not showing into input field as value <input id="output" type="text" value=""/> also for 121 is we need to be for example -> var finalRate = <?php echo $finalRate; ?>; but it's not working :(

Comment: Ah, right, because to set the value of an input you have to use `val()`, not `text()`  `text()` is used to set `<tag>thisIsText</tag>` @JamezRoz

Comment: please edit your answer so it's acceptable to other's let's first display output in input field as value

Comment: yup got it, but recent edit not working, even not display output in <div id="output"></div> we should display results into <input id="output" type="text" value=""/>

Comment: `$('#output').val(parseFloat(e.target.value)/finalRate);` will put the value into the input field, provided what you gave in your opening question.  I've edited the answer to include two debugging console logs.  You should include those in your logic to make sure the event is happening, and the values match what you are expecting.  And if they do not, you can debug from there.

Comment: i am new to programming i really can't debug on this stage, could you please do in js bin ? it's good to test live

Comment: I edited the answer to put the logic in a runnable snippet so you can see it running.  I commented out the php part since that is not supported onsite.  @JamezRoz

Comment: Here you can test than edit answer, http://jsbin.com/oleto5/5/edit?html,js,output

Comment: @JamezRoz  i've edited the answer here, on site, demonstrating that given the right value to the variable, it is performing the math and putting it in the output variable.  If something is not working correctly with the answer, then please reference that.  Otherwise if it is working here, but not in your actual script, then that becomes an issue that you, yourself, will need to debug to figure out where the differences are.  But in relation to your opening question, as far as I can tell this answer does what you asked for.

Comment: I am checking your answer live on jsbin http://jsbin.com/oleto5/5/edit?html,js,output

Comment: it's working but you have placed static value 121, it should be dynamic php variable